# how to find the maximum subsequence sum in a circular linked list

Tags: java, algorithm

I am aware of the maximum subarray sum problem and its O(n) algorithm. This questions modifies that problem by using a circular linked list:

**Find the sequence of numbers in a circular linked list with maximum sum.**
**Now what if sum of all entries is zero?**

To me, the only approach is to modify the array solution and have the algorithm loop around and start over at the beginning at the list once the first iteration is done. Then do the same thing for up to 2 times the entire list and find the max. The down side is that there might be many very tricky to handle if I do it this way, for example, if the list looks like:

2 - 2 - 2 - 2 back to front

Then it's very tricky to not include the same element twice

Is there a better algorithm?

Thanks!!

Comment: By opening the ring and replicating all elements but the last, you turn the circular problem to the standard linear one, and keep the O(N) behavior. [Actually you needn't replicate the elements, just access them modulo N.]

Comment: What if the array is fully positive? Eg: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Wouldn't repeating from the start after the first iteration give you 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 30 where the answer is 15? Or am I mis-understanding your approach ><

Comment: is it sub-sequence or sub-array? noted that sub-sequence does not require **consecutive numbers**, but sub-array does.

Comment: @RanaldLam surprise to find you here :)

Comment: @nevets OMG almost couldnt find out who you were >< hi! Btw, if the question was sub-sequence wouldnt the solution be quite trivial? (Eg. Just sum all the positive integers?)

Comment: @RanaldLam true that's why I wrote the sub-array solution, but still need to confirm with OP :P

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it doesn't matter if the datastructure is a linked list or an array, so I will use array for simplicity.

I don't really understand your algorithm, but it seems that you are going to do something like **duplicate the array at the back of the original, and run the Kadane's algorithm on this doubled-array**. This is a wrong approach, and a counter example has been given by @RanaldLam.

To solve it, we need to discuss it in three cases:

1. All negative. In this case, the maximum of the array is the answer, and an `O(N)` scan will do the job;
2. The maximum sub-array does not require a wrapping, for example `a = {-1, 1, 2, -3}`. In this case, a normal Kadane's algorithm will do the job, time complexity `O(N)`;
3. The maximum sub-array requires a wrapping, for example `a = {1, -10, 1}`. Actually, this case implies another fact: since elements inside the maximum sub-array requires a wrapping, then the elements that **are not inside the maximum sub-array does not require a wrapping**. Therefore, as long as we know the sum of these non-contributing elements, we can calculate the correct sum of contributing elements by subtracting max_non_contributing_sum from total sum of the array.

But how to calculate `max_non_contributing_sum` in case 3? This is a bit tricky: since these non-contributing elements do not require wrapping, so we can simply **invert the sign of every elements and run Kadane's algorithm on this inverted array**, which requires `O(N)`.

Finally, we should compare the sum of non-wrapping (case 2) and wrapping (case 3), the answer should be the bigger one.

As a summary, all cases require `O(N)`, thus the total complexity of the algorithm is `O(N)`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. But i don't really get your case three and why duplication fails for 1, -10, 1... In this case, i would do 1, -10, 1, 1, -10, which would give me the correct sum right?  And sorry, couldn't follow your algo for case three either.

Comment: oh it's an editing error and I didn't recognize that, sorry for that line. that line should not be there. I will explain it more in details.

Answer (score 0):

Your absolutly right. There is no better algorithm.